# Check if Struct already exists in array of structs

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

I am new to solidity. I have a struct and an array of structs, like this:

```
struct Adopter{
    uint age;
    uint gender; // 0 woman, 1 man
    // maybe add an id field
}

Adopter[] adopters;
```

So, a person can adopt an animal only once. How do I keep adopters in such a way that I can check if the person already has adopted an animal? I can't search for a struct inside an array of structs and I can't create a mapping (struct => bool). There must be a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: You can just have `bool adoptedPet` in the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a mapping of addresses to structs and include a boolean in the struct.

Be sure to check this pattern: https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a

Hope it helps.